# Sending file by wifi in android

Tags: android, wifi

Hi i want to send file direct by using wifi.
I search a lot in internet and find p2p wifi connection in developer.android site but problem is that not work on every phone , i mean just phones support p2p connection can use it.
So i looking for another way.
I find a android app name zapya that sending file from android phone to another phone and that work on every phone.
Can anyone say how that use wifi to send data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782367/how-to-transfer-files-between-two-android-phones-using-wifi-direct-to-download-d

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002222/file-transfer-over-wi-fi-in-android

Comment: https://github.com/mayfourth/WiFi-Direct-File-Transfer

Comment: thanks @naveen for your comment but i see this  project too https://github.com/mayfourth/WiFi-Direct-File-Transfer but when i use it , nothing happen i mean when i touche search button in client and start server in recive file nothing happen